# Why is an empty Excel file downloaded when I try to download a table in xlsx format using Flask?

Tags: python, flask

When you click on the download button, an empty excel file is downloaded. Tried two options, in both cases the same thing. Please tell me what is wrong. How to fix the code.

Download link

```
<a href = "{{url_for('download', columns = request.form.getlist('columns'), year = request.form.getlist('year'), indicators=request.form.getlist('indicators'), station=request.form.getlist('station'))}}" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>
```

**app.py option 1**

```
@app.route("/download", methods=["GET","POST"])
def download():
    if request.method == "GET":
        year = [int(i) for i in request.form.getlist("year") if i.isdigit()]
        station = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("station")]
        indicators = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("indicators")]
        columns = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("columns")]
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT {} FROM fact_indicators WHERE fact_year = ANY(%s) AND fact_indicators = ANY(%s) AND fact_station_name = ANY(%s);"
                    .format(",".join(["\"{}\"".format(c) for c in columns])),(year, indicators, station))
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close
        file_obj = io.BytesIO()
        # создаем новую книгу excel
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.active
        worksheet.append(columns)
        for row in rows:
            worksheet.append(list(row))           
        workbook.save(file_obj)
        file_obj.seek(0)
        filename = "fact_T2.xlsx"
        response = make_response(file_obj.read())
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; path={filename}"
        response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        return response
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

**app.py option 2**

```
@app.route("/download", methods=["GET","POST"])
def download():
    if request.method == "GET":
        year = request.form.getlist("year")
        year = [int(i) for i in request.form.getlist("year") if i.isdigit()]
        station = request.form.getlist("station")
        station = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("station")]
        indicators = request.form.getlist("indicators")
        indicators = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("indicators")]
        columns = request.form.getlist("columns")
        columns = [str(i) for i in request.form.getlist("columns")]
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT {} FROM fact_indicators WHERE fact_year = ANY(%s) AND fact_indicators = ANY(%s) AND fact_station_name = ANY(%s);"
                    .format(",".join(["\"{}\"".format(c) for c in columns])),(year, indicators, station))
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close
        filename = "fact_T2.xlsx"
        filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.active
        worksheet.append(columns)
        for row in rows:
            worksheet.append(list(row))           
        workbook.save(filepath)
        return send_from_directory(os.path.dirname(__file__),  path=filename, as_attachment=True)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

On the site itself, the table is unloaded correctly, prints for years, station, indicators, columns look like this (select multiple is used everywhere)

```
[2020, 2021, 2022] 
['dasd', 'mdasdas'] 
['dadasd'] 
['year', 'name', 'fact_q1', 'fact_q2', 'fact_q3', 'fact_q4', 'annual_values']
```

I see this in the terminal

```
"GET /download?columns=year&columns=name&columns=fact_q1&columns=fact_q2&columns=fact_q3&columns=fact_q4&columns=annual_values&year=2020&year=2021&year=2022&indicators=dadasd&station=dasd&station=mdasdas HTTP/1.1" 200
```